# Android material spinner NullPointerException on AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, exception, material-design, android-spinner

Getting android spinner NullPointerException when rotate the screen

Hi! guys I'm having trouble with a spiner throwing a nullPointerExpression when rotating the screen

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/department_spinner"
            android:hint="@string/select_department"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/spinner_icon"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorButton"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

**Inside my onCreateView**

```
    //MaterialBetterSpinner code goes from here
            this.materialDesignSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.department_spinner);
            materialDesignSpinner.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BE84"));
            materialDesignSpinner.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BE84"));

            materialDesignSpinner.setTextSize(17);
            materialDesignSpinner.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#00BE84"));
            materialDesignSpinner.setUnderlineColor(Color.parseColor("#00BE84"));

            callDepartment= service.getAllOpdIpdDepartments();

ArrayAdapter<String> departmentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(OpdIpdAnalysis.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
                materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(departmentAdapter);

            callDepartment.enqueue(new Callback<List<OpdIpdDepartmentModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<OpdIpdDepartmentModel>> call, Response<List<OpdIpdDepartmentModel>> response) {
                    departmentLists = response.body();

                    if (departmentLists != null){
                        for (int i = 0; i<departmentLists.size(); i++){
                            spinnerLists.add(departmentLists.get(i).getName());
                        }
                    }


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) materialDesignSpinner.getAdapter();

                adapter.clear();
                adapter.addAll(spinnerLists);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

**Here is the logcat:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ritecare, PID: 15345
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence,
>   android.widget.Filter$FilterListener)' on a null object reference
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1026)
>           at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onFocusChanged(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:49)
>           at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:7478)
>           at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:12441)
>           at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12415)
>           at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12382)
>           at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12324)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2166)
>           at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1563)
>           at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1518)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1346)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: Asif: Check this github issue of BetterSpinner library.
https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/77

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/53 and also the unavoidable ugly solution: https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/53#issuecomment-262440059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this during initialization of **MaterialBetterSpinner**:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> departmentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(OpdIpdAnalysis.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(departmentAdapter);
```

And inside **onResponse**:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) materialDesignSpinner.getAdapter();

adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(spinnerLists)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: It's preventing me to select data from the list and app still crashing with same exception.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, I have checked that. Did you correctly do that? Post your latest code please

Comment: **`ArrayAdapter<String> departmentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(OpdIpdAnalysis.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
        materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(departmentAdapter);`**, that shoud be outside of **onResponse**. Add this before this line: `callDepartment= service.getAllOpdIpdDepartments();`

Comment: Its freezing when rotating, and preventing me to select data from the list

Comment: I have created the adapter by empty `array`, that why when rotate it gets the empty one as during rotation view destroyed and recreated (**Do you know about Activity Life Cycle?**), That's why you can't select anything. If your implementation preserve **`spinnerLists`** data during rotation, then you can use this when create `ArrayAdapter` initially.

Comment: I told you the logic, you have to implement it by yourself. Thanks

Comment: First of all thank you, and yes I know about **Activity Life Cycle**. But i don't know the exact solution for this, that is why i'm asking solution here. And yes you give me your valuable time and i learned something new. Thank you again

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" Problem solved

Comment: Is it the solution you ask for? Please check your original question. Thanks

Comment: It's solved orientation problem for now, but i'll handle it using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState as i'm not using viewmodel in this project. Thank you

Comment: @SheikhAsifIqbal, What is the problem of my solution? You changed the accepted answer after long time. Is it wise?

Answer (score 0):

**I find a better material spinner library**

**We should use ganfra/MaterialSpinner library**

**It is simple and more robust**

**Here is the link:**

https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner